# How to list Java Card file system?

Tags: filesystems, javacard

Consider I have a Global Platfrm supported java card. I want to get a list of all files (Dedicated/elementary, fixed/variable, linear/transparent/cyclic files) on the card. Is there any APDU-based method or software to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global Platform is a method of managing applications and life cycles of a card. Java Card is a generic platform that is based but does not fully implement ISO 7816-4. So although it is based on a standard for file based cards, it doesn't implement anything [ed: of the file system] (other than of course SELECT by NAME). Hence, the answer is **no**: you would have to know the application or at least protocol implemented by the applets on the card.

A well known standard for finding files and objects on a file based is ISO 7816-15, which is the standard following up on PKCS#15 by RSA Laboratories (RIP). Beware that it is hugely complex and remind yourself that there are many implementations of ISO 7816-4 cards that are slightly incompatible, even if they have been designed as file based cards in the first place.